# Incorrect operation .exe file with pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a piece of code that is given below. When opening the .exe db is created and after that the program goes into an endless loop, trying to create more files and outputs an error that the products table already exists. Moreover, if you run the code using pycharm, everything works fine.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    now = datetime.now()
    time_now = now.strftime("%H %M")
    file_name = r'data/result1 ' + (str(date.today())) + ' ' + time_now + '.db'
    ittr = 0
    conn = sqlite3.connect(file_name)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE "products" (
                "категория" TEXT NOT NULL,
                "производитель" TEXT NOT NULL,
                "название"  TEXT NOT NULL,
                "цена"  TEXT NOT NULL,
                "продажи"   INTEGER NOT NULL,
                "наличие"   TEXT NOT NULL,
                "рейтинг"   TEXT NOT NULL,
                "отзывы"    TEXT NOT NULL,
                "айди"  TEXT NOT NULL
            );
                           """)
    conn.commit()
    with multiprocessing.Pool(1) as p:
        for i in range(190):
            start_id = 1 + 10000 * ittr
            end_id = 10000 + 10000 * ittr
            ittr = ittr + 1
            p.apply_async(main, args=(start_id,end_id, ), callback=data_processing)
        p.close()
        p.join()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found on the wiki that you need to immediately after `if __name__ == '__main__':` write `multiprocessing.freeze_support()` and everything worked!
For more information visit https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.freeze_support

Comment: Can you provide the link for the wiki? Thanks it will help other users if they encounter this problem